# After enabling ETF qdisc packets are only sent for a few seconds

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface, timestamps, socket

I have two computers that are connected via an Ethernet cable with Ubuntu 22.04 installed on them. I have a client on computer A) which is sending UDP packets to a server on computer B).  I am examining the effects of the ETF qdisc with a TAPRIO qdisc as its parent on the traffic. I used the c socket library for the source code of the client utilizing the SO_PRIORITY socket option with the SCM_TXTIME control message type.

In order to visualize the effects of the ETF qdisc, I set the txtime of each packet in a 5-second interval to the end of that 5 second interval. Therefore, I am expecting a burst in every 5 seconds on the server side.

The problem is that I can only see that burst 2 or 3 times on the server side right after changing from PFIFO qdisc to the mentioned ETF and TAPRIO qdisc setup. After that, no packets get sent from the client side. When switching back go PFIFO qdisc while keeping the client and server alive, the packets arrive as they should, without bursts. Changing to TAPRIO and ETF qdiscs while the client and server is alive again produces a few bursts and nothing more afterwards.

What can cause this behaviour?

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
//setting socket options:
static void setsockopt_txtime(int fd)
{
    struct sock_txtime so_txtime_val = { .clockid = CLOCK_TAI };
    struct sock_txtime so_txtime_val_read = { 0 };
    socklen_t vallen = sizeof(so_txtime_val);
    so_txtime_val.flags = (SOF_TXTIME_REPORT_ERRORS);
    if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TXTIME,
        &so_txtime_val, sizeof(so_txtime_val)))
        error(1, errno, "setsockopt txtime");

    if (getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TXTIME,
        &so_txtime_val_read, &vallen))
        error(1, errno, "getsockopt txtime");

    if (vallen != sizeof(so_txtime_val) ||
        memcmp(&so_txtime_val, &so_txtime_val_read, vallen))
        error(1, 0, "getsockopt txtime: mismatch");
}
//sending message and setting txtime for message
static int l2_send(int fd, void* buf, int len, __u64 txtime, struct sockaddr_in *servaddr)
{
    char control[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(txtime))] = {};
    struct cmsghdr* cmsg;
    struct msghdr msg;
    struct iovec iov;
    ssize_t cnt;

    iov.iov_base = buf;
    iov.iov_len = len;

    memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
    msg.msg_name = (struct sockaddr*)servaddr;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(*servaddr);

    msg.msg_iov = &iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;

    //We specify the transmission time in the CMSG.
    msg.msg_control = control;
    msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(control);

    cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);
    cmsg->cmsg_level = SOL_SOCKET;
    cmsg->cmsg_type = SCM_TXTIME;
    cmsg->cmsg_len = CMSG_LEN(sizeof(__u64));
    *((__u64*)CMSG_DATA(cmsg)) = txtime;

    cnt = sendmsg(fd, &msg, 0);
    if (cnt < 1) {
        //pr_err("sendmsg failed: %m");
        printf("sending message failed!\n");
        return cnt;
    }
    printf("messaage sent!\ntxtime:%lf\n\n",(double)txtime);
    return cnt;
}
double timer_difference(struct timespec* tval_before, struct timespec* tval_after, struct timespec* tval_result)
{
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_TAI, tval_after);
    timespecsub(tval_after, tval_before, tval_result);
    double time_elapsed = (double)tval_result->tv_sec + ((double)tval_result->tv_nsec / 1000000000.0f);
    return time_elapsed;
}


//Relevant part of main funtion for calculating txtime:
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
.
.
    struct timespec txtime_base,txtime_base_after,txtime_difference;    
    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    setsockopt_txtime(sockfd);
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    // Filling server information 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(server_port);
    inet_aton("10.0.0.70", &servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
    if (connect(sockfd , &servaddr,  sizeof(servaddr)))
        error(1, errno, "connect");

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_TAI, &txtime_base);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_TAI, &txtime_base_after);
    txtime = txtime_base.tv_sec * (__u64)1000000000+ TXTIME_PERIOD*(__u64)8*(__u64)1000000000 + txtime_base.tv_nsec;
  
        while (1)
        {
            if(TXTIME_PERIOD<timer_difference(&txtime_base,&txtime_base_after,&txtime_difference)) //setting txtime here
            {
                clock_gettime(CLOCK_TAI, &txtime_base);
                txtime = txtime_base.tv_sec * (__u64)1000000000+ (__u64)TXTIME_PERIOD*(__u64)2*(__u64)1000000000 + txtime_base.tv_nsec;
                printf("in txtime if!\n");
            }
            while (time_elapsed < send_interval)  //sending interval without txtime here
            {
                
                time_elapsed = timer_difference(&tval_before, &tval_after, &tval_result);               
            } 
            txtime=txtime+(__u64)1000;       //creating 1 μs gap betwwen packets of one burst
            l2_send(sockfd, (const char*)send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), txtime,&servaddr);
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is ARP packets don't have SO_TXTIME metadata flag set. ETF will drop every packet without SO_TXTIME flag, including ARP packets. Linux invalidate the neighbor entries AFAIR in every 30 secs, then it cannot resolve the 10.0.0.70 IP's MAC with ARP, since they are dropped.

A workaround, to use `mqprio` qdisc with an etf leaf on prio band != 0. In your code, you have to set some priority != 0 with `setsockopt(..., SO_PRIORITY, ...)` to the sender socket. That way, only the traffic you generate going through the ETF qdisc, and other traffic (e.g. ARP) uses the priority 0 which might have `pfifo_fast` or other qdisc, which dont drop the outgoing packet.

Alternative solution:
Use static neighbor entries, they are permanent and if Linux see the MAC for the IP in the neighbor table (or ARP table if thats more familiar):

`ip neigh add 10.0.0.70 dev eth0 lladdr 00:00:00:02:02:02` where `00:00:00:02:02:02` is the MAC address of the NIC which configured with the 10.0.0.70 IP.